# more simple than flip clock.js

Tags: javascript, flipclock

i have one simple page to show time remaining to start quiz.
i using this code for my countdown timer:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var clock;
  clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(
    863999999, {
      clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
      countdown: true,
      callbacks: {
        stop: function () {
          /* alert("Hello") */
        }
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.js"></script>

<div class="clock" style="margin:40px;"></div>
```

is there something more simple  and more lighter than "flip clock.js" , not using jquery as core?(fully javascript)

Answer (score 0):

http://bl.ocks.org/deltafactory/6e1cb71cfc8bb169181d

Pure and simple using CSS and HTML5. Animation should be no problem....

Comment: ty for answer but i need  full count down freamwork but much simple

Answer (score 0):

i found solution :

```js
        function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
            var t = endtime;
            var seconds = Math.floor(t % 60);
            var minutes = Math.floor((t / 60) % 60);
            var hours = Math.floor((t / (60 * 60)) % 24);
            var days = Math.floor(t / (60 * 60 * 24));
            return {
                'total': t,
                'days': days,
                'hours': hours,
                'minutes': minutes,
                'seconds': seconds
            };
        }


        function initializeClock(endtime) {

            var daysSpan = document.getElementById('days');
            var hoursSpan = document.getElementById('hours');
            var minutesSpan = document.getElementById('minutes');
            var secondsSpan = document.getElementById('seconds');

            function updateClock() {
                endtime = endtime - 1;
                var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

                daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
                hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
                minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
                secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

                if (t.total < 1) {
                    clearInterval(timeinterval);
                    alert("Hello");
                }
            }

            updateClock();
            var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
        }
```

```css
body{
 text-align: center;
 background: #00ECB9;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
}
h1{
    color: #396;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin: 40px 0px 20px;
}
#clockdiv{
 font-family: sans-serif;
 color: #fff;
 display: inline-block;
 font-weight: 100;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 30px;
}
#clockdiv > div{
 padding: 10px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background: #00BF96;
 display: inline-block;
}
#clockdiv div > span{
 padding: 15px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background: #00816A;
 display: inline-block;
}
.smalltext{
 padding-top: 5px;
 font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>some title</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="initializeClock(863999999);">
        <h1>Countdown Clock</h1>
        <div id="clockdiv">
            <div>
                <span id="days"></span>
                <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span id="hours"></span>
                <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span id="minutes"></span>
                <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span id="seconds"></span>
                <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        
    </body>
</html>
```

but i need javascript professionals check my code for bugs.